# Weird problem with Canon AE-1, the shutter curtain goes up after advancing the lever

Tags: canon, shutter, shutter-release

When I advance the lever the shutter curtain opens by itself without pressing the shutter button. The weird thing is that the shutter still fires and the curtain closes after that certain time. This does not happen every time but after a few advances it opens by itself and stays there until I release the shutter. I checked the magnets all seem to work fine and also the battery level is normal.

[Here's a slow motion video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fYiGHHok6D1FUgfhXXHYQglbVKUlxDl1/view) I made of the shutter being pressed and the film lever being operated.

Comment: I believe that the shutter on that camera moves horizontally, side to side, not up and down. The mirror moves up to allow the light to pass through to the film when the shutter opens. "*it goes up and stays there until I release the shutter*" Does that mean you are holding the shutter release button down ? Is shutter speed set to  **B**  ( Bulb mode )  ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gQIA8tXTEg

Comment: The curtain does not go up only the mirror goes up. The rolling shutter moves **sideways**, or horizontally.  Yes there are two curtains, One curtain moves from left to right, followed by the second shutter curtain, there is an open space between the two curtains that is allowing the light to come through. The time that the  opens space between the two curtains stays open is controlled by you when you set the shutters speed dial.

Comment: One curtain moves over,( *sideways left to right* ) the opening is allowed to be open for the set time, the second curtain follows in the same direction ( *sideways left to right* ) closing the space. When you advance the film both curtains are moved back to the left so it is ready for the next exposure. All of this can be witnessed if you open the back of the camera  and watch as you release the shutter and actuate the film advance lever. DO NOT TOUCH THE SHUTTER CURTAIN !

Comment: Thanks I was wrong about how the shutter works so I took a slo-mo video of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fYiGHHok6D1FUgfhXXHYQglbVKUlxDl1/view

Comment: Slow motion, **good idea**. I may have the left to  right backwards. I am not sure if the shutter is not firing completely or it is not resetting properly but is not functioning as it should. Sorry i cant say more. I think you need to take into a camera repair shop. It could be a simple as dried out lubrication. You may learn a great deal watching YouTube videos, but opening and working on these cameras with all of there tiny parts is not for the faint of heart or mechanically challenged.

Answer (score 2):

Based on viewing the [slow motion video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fYiGHHok6D1FUgfhXXHYQglbVKUlxDl1/view) you posted:

Something is causing the first shutter curtain to reopen as the film winding lever reaches the end of its travel. This is a malfunction that should not be occurring. Your camera needs to be examined by an experienced camera repairman familiar with 1970s era Canon cameras. Good look finding one in 2020.

The Canon AE-1 has a horizontally moving set of fabric curtains that begin with the first curtain covering the film gate between the light box and the film. When the shutter button is fully depressed to take a picture the first curtain opens by moving to the left (as viewed from behind the camera). At the interval prescribed by the selected shutter duration ("shutter speed"), the second curtain closes from right to left to cover the film gate. Note that the curtains always move at the same speed across the film gate. What determines exposure time ("shutter speed") is the interval between when the first curtain begins to open and the second curtain begins to close.

When the film winder lever is moved the shutter curtains are also reset by moving from left to right. They overlap slightly so that no light is allowed through the film gate as they move. The second curtain disappears to the right as the first curtain reappears to cover the film gate opening.